# Не получается вернуть массив из функции при помощи return?

Tags: php

```
function definition($pnd){
    $ar_pnd = array();

    foreach($pnd as $pndOtd){
        array_push($ar_pnd, $pndOtd->branch);
    }
    $ar_pnd = array_unique($ar_pnd);
    $arr_otd = $ar_pnd;

    return $arr_otd;
}

$pndid = 'number_'. $_GET['pnd'];
$pnd = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $pndid" );
definition($pnd);

var_dump($arr_otd);
```

Возвращает `NULL`, хотя если его выводить в функции - все работает, почему не получается вернуть?

Comment: Попробуйте всё-таки `return array_unique($ar_pnd);`

Comment: все равно null отдает

Comment: вы результат  не сохраняете никуда, у вас переменная не определена вне функции

Comment: @teran Почему бы автору не написать что надо результат функции в переменную записать таким `$arr_otd = definition($pnd)` ,

Comment: сделал переменную $arr_otd над функцией - вернуло NULL, сделал вызов функции в переменной - вернуло NULL. Или я не так что-то сохраняю?

Comment: @ЮраГорячев Вы исходный пост отредактируйте с учетом ваших последних правок с добавлением $arr_otd.

Comment: если вы переменную определили над функцией, то внутри функции ее надо определить как `global`. Почитайте справку на предмет области видимости переменных

Answer (score -1):

```
    function definition($pnd){
    $ar_pnd = array();

    foreach($pnd as $pndOtd){
        $ar_pnd[] = [$pndOtd->branch];
    }


    return array_unique($ar_pnd);
}

$pndid = 'number_'. $_GET['pnd'];
$pnd = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $pndid" );
definition($pnd);



var_dump($arr_otd);
```

Comment: var_dump делай внтури функси сначальо )